# How can I insert Dynamic JSON data into MySql DB with JSON data type?

Tags: mysql, database, mule4

I want to insert real time json payload into MySql DB. But I am unable to do so. I am trying to achieve it via mule 4. I am prompted the below error:-
**Data truncation: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.**
Please help.

Comment: Please share how do you generate the JSON (using DataWeave?) and the database connector operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql DB expects String as parameter in the SQL statement. Your component sends data as object. Word "binary" indicates it.

Send data as String. Convert your JSON object to string as described here https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/Object_as_string.html

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
var x={abc:"xyz","key":"value"}
output application/java
---
write(x,'application/json')
```